# How to make regex expression for alphanumeric and some special characters?

Tags: javascript

I'm using regular expression -

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*$/
```

to accept alphanumeric and some special characters for the string validation in **JS**. But, I don't want all string characters to be special characters only. Please suggest a valid regular expression for this case.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest testing your second condition with a second regex. One like you have to see that there are only valid characters, and a second like `/[0-9a-zA-Z]/` to see that it has at least one alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

You could express your regex as:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*$
```

This says to match at least one pure alphanumeric character, with optional other alphas or symbol characters.

```
^                             start of the string
[0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*  match zero or more alphas or symbols
[0-9a-zA-Z]                   match one alphanumeric character
[0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*  match zero or more alphas or symbols
$                             end of the string
```

For a slightly more terse regex, you could also use a positive *lookahead*:

```
^(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways.

- "any number of alphanumeric or special" followed by "alphanumeric" followed by "any number of alphanumeric or special" (asserts that there is at least one alphanumeric in there)

  ```
  ^[0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*$
  ```
- assert at the start "lookahead: any number of characters later, there will be an alphanumeric"

  ```
  ^(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z ~!@#$%^&*-_+=|?]*$
  ```